# Advise on creating the most simple PHP Templating/frameworks

Tags: php, frameworks, smarty, templating

Let say i'm creating simple cms website using php which contain less than 10 pages. Eg: index.php, products.php, faq.php, buy.php, contact.php, etc. And i guess the best crawl for search engine is by creating the html templating or frameworks. Please advise me. which one is the most simple frameworks should i use? smarty, django, etc? basic coding process how it works or integrate would be helpful.

Comment: For such small sites you can use WordPress itself. It will make the development faster as most of the things are pre-built or available through plugins. You can get it here: http://wordpress.com/

Comment: i've created hundreds of website before using, joomla, wordpress, prestashop, xoops, mambo, etc but i only know 10% of the code and too complicated. i like to use my own coded, then i know every single code in there why and where..

Comment: Well then u should just start from scratch to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: thanks to user for the down votes with no reason.. that's help a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am use Twig templates in all projects (If project have many dynamic pages).

If your have a small project (Not full dynamic pages), your can use `*.php` files as templates.

As example:

```
function render($file, array $vars)
{
    ob_start();
    extract($vars);
    include '/path/to/theme/' . $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And use function `extract` in project - not good idea, but if project is small, then can use... But this is how you choose to